# What is a "suburban valley (belly) street"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard in the movie description of the film *[The 40-Year-Old Virgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_40-Year-Old_Virgin)*:

> In a helmet, he pedals his mirror-equipped bike along a **suburban belly street**.

The scene shows the protagonist pedaling a bike in a quiet and scenic neighborhood, along a straight residential street lined with trees. It does not make much sense to me. Does **belly street** mean anything? It could also be "valley street". It doesn't sound like a proper name to me either. As far as I can find, the setting doesn't specify a city/state. I am putting the [audio clip here for reference](https://clyp.it/00dmfwld).

Comment: Judging from the clip title, it seems like you're not sure if you hear "belly" or "valley". You should include that kind of detail in your posts. Also, I think details like a description of the street (straight, curved, cul-de-sac, etc.) and the area/city could be helpful.

Comment: The speaker says **valley** but I have no idea what **a suburban valley street** means. Unless the name of the place is Suburban Valley, though that would be odd.

Comment: Could be the San Fernandy Valley in California, which is referred to simply as "the Valley" ... but it could also refer to [other American valley areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Valley).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Belly street" doesn't mean anything to me. She says "valley".

#### A suburban valley street

I thought it was a strange expression, but I guess they wanted you to imagine a street in a suburb in a valley.

#### A suburban *V*alley street

There is a possibility that it is, in fact, proper. Since you told us the movie, it turns out the movie was filmed mostly in the San Fernando Valley, according to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/locations). The San Fernando Valley is colloquially known as "the Valley". If the writers of the audio description were aware of this, they might have meant it as *a suburban **V**alley street*: a street in the (San Fernando) Valley typical of one of its suburbs.